# SWT TabFolder: How do you automatically compress TabItems when there are too many

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a TabFolder in which the TabItems can be created dynamically.  I was expecting the tabs to compress like they would in a browser when you have more than will fit on the screen, but they just keep expanding to the right off the screen unless I add a horizontal scroll.  Is there a way to make them automatically compress like that?

```
TabFolder tabsComposite = new TabFolder(builder, SWT.NONE);
tabsComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
GridData tabsLayoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
tabsComposite.setLayoutData(tabsLayoutData);
```

These are created via button click in another method and any number of them can be created

```
TabItem item = new TabItem(tabsComposite, SWT.NONE);
tableComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
GridData tableLayoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
tableComposite.setLayoutData(tableLayoutData);
GridLayout tableLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
tableComposite.setLayout(tableLayout);
item.setText(nameText.getText());
```

Comment: I don't think `TabFolder` does this, but `CTabFolder` does support this.

Comment: I tried using that but it apparently doesn't include that behavior by default.  Do you know how to configure it to do that?

Comment: f I read the source correctly CTabFolder needs a `setMinimumCharacters(....)` call. It should then switch to using a 'chevron' last item if the tabs can't be displayed with the minimum characters. You can see this behavior in the Eclipse editor area tabs if you open a lots of editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @greg-449 mentioned, you can accomplish this with a `CTabFolder`. By default, the `CTabFolder` will display no fewer than [20 characters](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20Custom%20Widgets/common/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolder.java#L124) when compressed, so you may not have noticed this default behavior if the tab title were not sufficiently long.

You can call [`CTabFolder.setMinimumCharacters(int)`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolder.html#setMinimumCharacters-int-) if you want to change this value.

Default behavior:

[image]

With a new minimum set:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try.

Comment: @ShaneBurgel Glad to hear it! Please consider accepting the answer if you feel it was sufficient.

Comment: Done, sorry I missed that.  Thanks again